# Webservice call speed with Smart Card

Tags: java, web-services, keystore, smartcard

i have question about speed for WebService call while using Smart Card for authentication. Cann i do anything to speed up this? If i call public web service speed is few seconds. Is something wrong with code?
These are times:

```
07:48:31: ->Kreiranje trust manager-a --Trust Manager
07:48:31: ->keystore manager -- Keystore Manager
07:48:43:-> ssl context 
07:48:43: -> postavljanje konekcije --request parameters
07:48:43: ->slanje podataka -- sending data
07:49:00: -> primanje podataka -- receiving data
07:49:01: ->ispis podataka

public void callWS() {

        String soapMessage = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:hz=\"http://www.hz....hr/\">"
                + "<soapenv:Header/>"
                + "<soapenv:Body>"
                + "<hz>"
                + "<!--You have a CHOICE of the next 3 items at this level-->"
                + "<hz>155232113</hz>"
                + "</hz>"
                + "</soapenv:Body>"
                + "</soapenv:Envelope>";

        HttpsURLConnection connSSL = null;

        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar
                .getInstance().getTime());

        System.out.println(timeStamp + ": ->Kreiranje trust manager-a");

        TrustManager[] trustAll = { new X509TrustManager() {
            @Override
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs,
                    String authType) {
            }

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs,
                    String authType) {
            }

            public boolean isServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs) {
                return true;
            }

            public boolean isClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs) {
                return true;
            }
        } };

        timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar
                .getInstance().getTime());

        System.out.println(timeStamp + ": ->keystore manager");

        try {

            KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory
                    .getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());

            KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY", "SunMSCAPI");

            ks.load(null, null);

            kmf.init(ks, null);
            // KeyManager[] myKms = { new MyX509KeyMananger(this.p12File,
            // this.privateKeyPassword) };

            timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar
                    .getInstance().getTime());

            System.out.println(timeStamp + ":-> ssl context");

            SSLContext sslcont = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");

            // kmf.getKeyManagers()
            sslcont.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), trustAll, null);
            SSLSocketFactory factory = sslcont.getSocketFactory();

            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(factory);

            timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar
                    .getInstance().getTime());

            System.out.println(timeStamp + ": -> postavljanje konekcije");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // throw new
            // ConnectionManagerException("No Such Algorithm Exception: " +
            // e.getMessage());
            System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
            // throw new ConnectionManagerException("Key Management Exception: "
            // + e.getMessage());

            System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // throw new
            // ConnectionManagerException("MyX509KeyManager Exception: " +
            // e.getMessage());

            System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        String res = "";

        String url = "https:.....";
        String SOAPAction = "https:/operation";

        try {

            URL urlSSL = new URL(null, url);

            BufferedReader in;

            connSSL = (HttpsURLConnection) urlSSL.openConnection();
            connSSL.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
            connSSL.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",
                    String.valueOf(soapMessage.length()));
            connSSL.setRequestProperty("SOAP-Action", SOAPAction);
            connSSL.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connSSL.setDoOutput(true);
            connSSL.setConnectTimeout(5000);

            timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar
                    .getInstance().getTime());

            System.out.println(timeStamp + ": ->slanje podataka");

            /*
             * PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter( new
             * OutputStreamWriter(connSSL.getOutputStream())));
             * out.println(soapMessage); out.flush();
             */

            DataOutputStream wr = null;
            wr = new DataOutputStream(connSSL.getOutputStream());

            wr.writeBytes(soapMessage);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar
                    .getInstance().getTime());

            System.out.println(timeStamp + ": -> primanje podataka");

            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    connSSL.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
            String inputLine;
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                res = res + inputLine;

            }
            in.close();
            connSSL.disconnect();

            timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar
                    .getInstance().getTime());

            System.out.println(timeStamp + ": ->ispis podataka");

            System.out.println(res);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

    }
```

Comment: 2 suggestions that's worth looking into --- 1. do you have to init the keystore per every call? Can you not load the KeyStore and Factory just once ? From what I can see there is no request specific information going there.  2. Consider reusing the connection objects. They are costly to create. You can have some kind of pooled connections. Apache commons provides a pooling implementation you can use.

Comment: First of all you should try to profile your application (for instance with jconsole http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html) to determine which methods are slow and where the execution flow is waiting

Comment: ty for responses, finally i got .pfx and now speed is ~4 seconds.. this is gonna be final solution for authorization and authentication.